# How to turn on flyspell mode with AUCTeX?

Tags: spelling, emacs, auctex

I'm using `flyspell` mode, but unfortunatly I have to `M-x flyspell-mode` in each AUCTeX buffer.

Somehow `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'flyspell-mode)` doesn't work for me.

What is the correct `flyspell`-hook in AUCTeX?

Comment: There is an emacs StackExchange site, shouldn't this question be there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try 
`(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(flyspell-mode t))`

This will force flyspell-mode to turn on, instead of toggling it.

Comment: thanks. That worked. removing the hook worked as well. The hook might have been sourced somehow otherwise (from text-mode?).

Comment: This does not work the way you think it works. You probably enabled the flyspell-mode before in your text-mode-hook. The above code does not work and so does not disable the flyspell-mode.

Comment: This does not work. I am getting the same error as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42335854/why-is-latex-mode-replaced-by-fundamental-mode. The answer below does work for me.

Answer (score 10):

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook '(flyspell-mode t))
```

I would be surprised if the above worked.

The following works (using emacs 24):

```
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook #'turn-on-flyspell)
```

Comment: This worked for me. The above didn't.

Comment: indeed, this one works instead of the above. Emacs 26.3.